# How to follow redirect other link with server's post in spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm connecting with two local servers post parameters for redirect link. But not change url and web view after posting the parameters. I get only `response.toString()` (html string like ...."). How I change redirect link and view.

I found other questions and answers that are not easy to understand.

```
try {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/myproject/payreq");
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""
                + Integer.toString(postParams.getBytes().length));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection
            .getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    rd.close(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I expect change my project link's 8080 from redirect follow other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect to a different server, completetely on the server side, without the user noticing a change in the browser URL, use `forward:` redirection:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/myurl")
    public String redirectWithUsingForwardPrefix(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("attribute", "forwardWithForwardPrefix");
        return "forward:/http://localhost:9090/myproject/payreq";
    }
}
```